# Encryption and Decryption Video LINK with key

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption, codeigniter-3, php-7

I want to Encrypt and Decrypt Video LINK

```
<iframe d="ytplayer" width="972" height="284" src='<?php echo $fetchorderdetails['video_links'];?>' frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture">
```

I tried the below code...

```
<?php
$this->encryption->initialize(array('driver' => 'openssl'));
$plain_text =  $fetchorderdetails[0]['video_links'];
$ciphertext = $this->encryption->encrypt($plain_text);
echo $ciphertext;
echo $this->encryption->decrypt($ciphertext);
?>
```

above code is working correctly but problem is I want to decrypt with key and UserId
I am having UserId in session
$this->session->userdata('id');